# Is it possible to run an Excel macro-powered file on a server?

Tags: design, architecture, algorithms, web-development, excel

I've an Excel file (offline, on my computer) that elaborates medium-large amount of data using VBA Macros. Basically, this Excel macro-powered file works with a person that adds the data to an Excel sheet, then clicks a button and finally gets a new sheet with the elaborated data.

**I would like to provide the elaboration functionality online** (through a website) **avoiding to give my precious Excel file to people.**

To make that, I thought about implementing the following process:

1. The user upload to the website the data e.g. a CSV file.
2. The server elaborates the data using the Excel macro-powered file.
3. The user download the elaborated file.

Is it possible? If so, how e.g. where could I get started?

Comment: [“Is it possible to…”](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question) is not a really a question well suited for this site. ["Where to start", too.](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start). To make this more clear, I could answer here "Yes, it is possible." and "start by setting up a Windows server with a website providing upload and download capabilties". But I guess you would not perceive this as a very useful answer.

Comment: You'd have to use the various facilities for Excel interop - whether the VSTO tools in DotNet, or the native COM components (if outside DotNet). With these, you can instantiate the Excel application, open files, and copy data in and out. If you aren't familiar with these already though, then I'd budget weeks if not months of learning curve to achieve a stable and maintainable solution.

Comment: ... I would recommend to read both of those meta articles and follow their advice how to improve your question. This will take some time and effort to make it right, but otherwise don't be astonished fif the question will be closed and downvoted by our community.

Comment: Said that, I would heavily recommend against using Excel interop on a web server - some explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36638737/run-excel-on-server-c-sharp-interop-excel) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2). Better port the "elaboration process" (whatever that means in your case) into a programmin language & runtime environment better suited for server-side processing.